# can I run an ASP.NET application on a node server?

Tags: node.js, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2022

I've got a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter on AWS. It has a node.js server running on it (which I programmed). The main entry point listens on port 80 and delegates incoming traffic to the appropriate website using bouncy:

```
const bouncy = require('bouncy');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

bouncy(function(req, bounce) {
    const host = req.headers.host;
    if (host === 'shahspace.com' || host === 'www.shahspace.com') {
        bounce(8000);
    }
    if (host === 'assertivesolutions.ca' || host === 'www.assertivesolutions.ca') {
        bounce(8001);
    }
}).listen(80);

const shahspaceApp = express();
shahspaceApp
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'shahspace.com')))
    .listen(8000);
    
const assertSolApp = express();
assertSolApp
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assertivesolutions.ca')))
    .listen(8001);
```

As you can see, I've got two websites so far, assertivesolutions.ca and shahspace.com. Shahspace.com is a pre-existing old ASP.NET application that I'm porting over to this server. Since it doesn't have IIS installed, the website doesn't work. As soon as I navigate to an aspx file, it just gets downloaded rather than runs. I understand that asp.net applications require IIS to run, but I'm wondering if there's any way around this if I don't have IIS installed.

Thank you.

Comment: As it is a Win server, install (enable) asp.net but since you have port 80 used by node js, configure IIS to run say on port 8080

Comment: You can Configured IIS with New Port (Like. 8080,5000,XXXX etc)

Comment: So you're both saying to install IIS?

Comment: If you want to build a production environment, then IIS is your only option from Microsoft to host ASP.NET WebForms apps.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will pursue that (only) option.